# Remote GUI execution on Windows 10

Tags: windows, remote-access, rdp, psexec

I'm now around 15h into this issue and Windows refuses *every* attempt to find a solution.

I got a public room of 20 Windows 10 machines which serve questionnaires to users over either a website or a local program (think Kiosk PCs). To control these I have an administration machine which should start and stop these different programs on all/some machines at the same time (for that I wrote already an Python Qt-App).

On all machines runs the same Domainwide user (which of course is not an administator) and each machine has a local administrator account.

Which methods works most reliable to execute the GUI Applications?
I tried:

- PSExec (slow as hell, needs root and doesn't sees network drives)
- SSH (freeSSHd, openSSH, both aren't able to startup)
- doit (from Simon Tatham, just doesn't work)

Comment: did you search for this online?

Comment: Yeah, a lot. Most solutions rely on PSExec which as far as I see it, doesn't support these circumstances. I would just like to now from experience of others what is used succesfully in production enviroments.